# jquery mobile navigation link not working on first click

Tags: apache, cordova, jquery-mobile, navigation, intel-xdk

I am creating an apache cordova application using jquery mobile.
I have a login page where on successful login the page is redirected to mainpage.html by using ***$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "mainpage.html");***
On the mainpage.html I have a multipage template using a navabar. The code is below:-

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" data-icon="home" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#pagetwo" data-icon="arrow-r" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Page Two</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>With the ui-btn-active class, notice that the Home button stays highlighted (selected).</p>
    <p>If you click on the Page Two, you will notice that none of the buttons are highlighted (selected).</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>My Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#pageone" data-icon="home" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Page Two</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>No buttons are pre-selected (highlighted) in this page..</p>
    <p>To get the selected look for each button that represents the page you are actually on, go back to our navbar tutorial and read the next step to find out how!</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>My Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the ***Page Two*** tab it does not load at the first time. On clicking it once more, it loads the div with the id ***page two***

Can you please help me to correct the issue of not loading the page two at the first click?

Comment: Pls edit your post to make it clear, that the problem is only occurring when the page is loaded with `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "mainpage.html");` and add the relevant code from the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

**The lazy solution:**
Change the Page with pure javascript.

```
location.href = "mainpage.html";
```

**The complicated / dirty solution**

I was able to reproduce your problem.

The Problem is, how jquery-mobile handles the ajax navigation. If you link from `page1.html` to `page2.html`. Jquery-mobile will look into `page2.html` and take only the first `div` with the `data-role="page"` and load it into `page1.html`

If you link to a multipage, you will always get the first page and nothing more. To change this, you have to add `rel="external"` to the link. This way the framework load the entire page, header and all pages included.

With this knowledge, the only thing we should change on the `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "mainpage.html")` to say jqm that he should reload the page.
[The Api doc](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) says that there is a option `reload` or `reloadPage` (deprecated). But unfortunately this change nothing. I don't know if it doesnt work or if i don't understand the option right.

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "mainpage.html",  {reloadPage : true});
```

if you append the option `dataUrl : "mainpage.html"` the `pagetwo` is still not loading into the DOM, but the anchor to `pagetwo` is working.
But you will notice a mess in the browsers url-bar (start.html#mainpage.html)

```
 $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "mainpage.html",  {reloadPage : true, dataUrl : "mainpage.html"});
```

Now you can apend another option `changeHash: false` to not change the hash/url when you load the new page.

```
 $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "mainpage.html",  {reloadPage : true, dataUrl : "mainpage.html", changeHash: false});
```

This way you don't get a mess in the browsers url-bar. But you can't navigate back with the browsers back button. And a reload with will bring you to the previous page.